# Is there a way to write something like a fieldformatter/widget but for exposed filters shown in a view?

Tags: views

Here for example, I would like to make a widget or some way, that I can use this type of drop down always for one type of exposed filter, such as a published status. Thanks!

[image: Exposed Filter Example]

Comment: Those are just standard form elements, you can do whatever you'd like to them in the normal way via `hook_form_alter`. Or install Better Exposed Filters and Select2, as it sounds like that's what you're after

Comment: I actually can't install stuff like that at the moment, but this is good to know, thanks Clive!